Computation of Hochschild cohomology for a graded algebra
Let $k$ be a field and $A= k[x]/(x^2)$ with $|x|=2\ell+1$ is a graded algebra, consider the module $M=k$ over $A$ with the module structure induced by the map $\epsilon: A \to M$ given by $\epsilon (x) =0$ and $\epsilon (1)=1.$ One can define the Hochschild cochain as $C^{n,m} (A, M):= \mbox{Hom}^m_k(A^{\otimes_k n}, M)$ - all degree $m$ maps from $A^{\otimes_k n}\to  M$. Define the graded Hochschild co-boundary $\delta: C^{n-1,m} (A, M) \to C^{n,m} (A, M) $ as $$\delta \theta (a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_n) = \epsilon (a_1)\theta (a_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\theta (a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes  a_n) + (-1)^n \theta (a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{n-1}) \epsilon (a_n).$$
I am looking help to compute the Hochschild cohomology $HH^{\ast, \ast} (A, M).$
